# How to get the index of input value is not empty only

Tags: javascript

```js
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((v,i)=>{
  if(v.value !== undefined || v.value !== '') {
   console.log(i)
   }
})
})
```

```html
<input type='text' class='t1'>

<input type='text' class='t2'>

<button>Click</button>
```

I only want to get the `index` of the input value is not empty. Not sure why the `if` check isn't working.

Comment: Just perform the check for `if (v.value !== '') { ... }` (or just `if (v.value) { ... }`), because `v.value` is *never* undefined. The first part of your conditional statement will always evaluate to true, that's why you will always pass the `if` test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited: try this

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function(){
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach((v,i)=>{

     if(v.value) {
   console.log(i)
   }
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To handle the blank spaces as well I would do it like this:

```
if(v.value.length > 0 && v.value.trim() != "") {
   console.log(i)
}
```